# Why elasticsearch index performance falls down after frequent write

Tags: elasticsearch

When I start nodejs script, it deletes old index (if it exist) and according to the config file creates new, after creates Websocket-server and starts to listen incoming connections.

```
initES() {
    this.elasticsearchClient = new elasticsearch.Client({
      host: `${Config.elasticSearchHost}:${Config.elasticSearchPort}`,
      log: 'trace'
    });

    let deletePromise = this.elasticsearchClient.indices.delete({index: `${Config.elasticSearchIndex}`});
    deletePromise.then(() => {
      console.log(`Index ${Config.elasticSearchIndex} deleted`);
    }, function(e) {
      console.log(e.toJSON())
    }).then(() => {
      let createPromise = this.elasticsearchClient.indices.create({
        index: `${Config.elasticSearchIndex}`,
        body: {
          settings: {
            index: {
              number_of_shards: 1,
              number_of_replicas: 0
            },
            analysis: {
              analyzer: {
                whitespace_analyzer: {
                  tokenizer: 'whitespace',
                  filter: ['lowercase']
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      });
      createPromise.then(() => {
        console.log(`Index ${Config.elasticSearchIndex} created`);
      }, (e) => {
        console.log(e.toJSON());
      })
    });
  }
```

Script is intended to start just once, at the boot time (through cron), it was written by me, and uses standart ES library (
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html
).

In front, user chooses to calculate orders (~700 items, they calculate by system automatically, with gearman and phantomjs)

At first (first 8 hours or first test) everything is working fine, ES responding good, websocket clients frequently update data, and data is updated in ES index.

If user cancels process, or process is finished and user decides to recalculate (all data is deleted before anything is put on), process of IO in ES becomes slower.

And so on, and after awhile index is filled up to ~340.. ~350 items, not to 700. In some cases ES stops to respond.

Tailing log files of ES shows me tons of lines

```
Entering safepoint region: GenCollectForAllocation
[2019-05-21T13:46:45.611+0000][9630][gc,start     ] GC(271) Pause Young (Allocation Failure)
[2019-05-21T13:46:45.611+0000][9630][gc,task      ] GC(271) Using 8 workers of 8 for evacuation
[2019-05-21T13:46:45.616+0000][9630][gc,age       ] GC(271) Desired survivor size 17891328 bytes, new threshold 6 (max threshold 6)
[2019-05-21T13:46:45.617+0000][9630][gc,age       ] GC(271) Age table with threshold 6 (max threshold 6)
[2019-05-21T13:46:45.617+0000][9630][gc,age       ] GC(271) - age   1:     987344 bytes,     987344 total
[2019-05-21T13:46:45.617+0000][9630][gc,age       ] GC(271) - age   2:       5440 bytes,     992784 total
[2019-05-21T13:46:45.617+0000][9630][gc,age       ] GC(271) - age   3:     172640 bytes,    1165424 total
[2019-05-21T13:46:45.617+0000][9630][gc,age       ] GC(271) - age   4:     535104 bytes,    1700528 total
[2019-05-21T13:46:45.617+0000][9630][gc,age       ] GC(271) - age   5:     333224 bytes,    2033752 total
[2019-05-21T13:46:45.617+0000][9630][gc,age       ] GC(271) - age   6:        128 bytes,    2033880 total
[2019-05-21T13:46:45.617+0000][9630][gc,heap      ] GC(271) ParNew: 282158K->2653K(314560K)
[2019-05-21T13:46:45.617+0000][9630][gc,heap      ] GC(271) CMS: 88354K->88355K(699072K)
[2019-05-21T13:46:45.617+0000][9630][gc,metaspace ] GC(271) Metaspace: 85648K->85648K(1128448K)
[2019-05-21T13:46:45.617+0000][9630][gc           ] GC(271) Pause Young (Allocation Failure) 361M->88M(989M) 5.387ms
[2019-05-21T13:46:45.617+0000][9630][gc,cpu       ] GC(271) User=0.01s Sys=0.00s Real=0.00s
[2019-05-21T13:46:45.617+0000][9630][safepoint    ] Leaving safepoint region
[2019-05-21T13:46:45.617+0000][9630][safepoint    ] Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0057277 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000429 seconds
[2019-05-21T13:46:46.617+0000][9630][safepoint    ] Application time: 1.0004453 seconds
[2019-05-21T13:46:46.617+0000][9630][safepoint    ] Entering safepoint region: Cleanup
[2019-05-21T13:46:46.617+0000][9630][safepoint    ] Leaving safepoint region
```

But to be precise, I dont see anyting critical (except memory failure allocation).
And even if everything go well these lines also appear in log.

If I restart my script (which deletes old and creates new index), ES updates these items fast, as it does only for first time

So my question is:

Why ES looses it's performance if I 
`insert/update/read/delete data ... insert/update/read/delete data ...`

and its working ok, if I
`insert/update/read restart script insert/update/read/`
?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to do with Elasticsearch.

It was my fault in not closing websocket connections, which led to server slow down, loosing it's resources.

Sorry guys for taking your time